# Program automation

Tags: automation, sas

I like to be enlightened on how to carry out a sas program automation to run a monthly expense  for some 10 clients within a claim dataset. The program I ran below has to be automated and and used to populate different clients in a major dataset.
I have my program up and running for the first subdata (first client) as stated below  for some variables F, G, H, I, L, M and N:

```
 DATA ATD;
    SET APC;
  /*F*/
 IF PC IN ('F') AND 0 <= RSCW <= 2 THEN DO;
 RK = 1; PT= 20; END;
 IF PC IN ('F') AND 2 <= RSCW <= 3.1 THEN DO;
 RK = 2; PT= 40; END;
 IF PC IN ('F') AND 3.1 <= RSCW <= 5.3 THEN DO;
 RK = 3; PT= 60; END;
 IF PC IN ('F') AND 5.3 <= RSCW <= 11.5 THEN DO;
 RK = 4; PT= 80; END;
 IF PC IN ('F') AND RSCW > 11.5 THEN DO;
 RK = 4; PT= 100; END;
   /*G*/
 IF PC IN ('F') AND 0 <= RSCW <= 1.8 THEN DO;
 ......
 /*N*/
 IF PC IN ('F') AND 0 <= RSCW <= 1.8 THEN DO;
 END;
RUN;
```

This happens to be my very first time trying automation out, kindly guide and help me out here.   The program needs to be run on the Toad for same clients very month.

Comment: You don't have nearly enough information in the question to answer it properly.  What OS are you running?  How are you running SAS?  Why do you mention Toad, which is not as far as I know related to SAS (typically used to connect to Oracle, at least in my world)?

Comment: The toad I mentioned is actually of no effect, that's where I'll eventually upload my populated dataset.

Comment: My main task is to automate my SAS program developed and to run the monthly claims that comes in. The OS is windows.

Comment: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Scheduling_SAS_Jobs
and
http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Batch_processing_under_Windows
are probably helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My previous site use Win XP Scheduled Tasks to call PuTTY PLINK to remote run many SAS programs in various scripts in AIX machines daily/weekly/monthly.

Your case is more simple.  Just use Win XP Scheduled Tasks to monthly run bat files.  In the bat file, call the SAS exe with all program file, log file, autoexec SAS files , SAS config files and output listing files as command line parameters.

If you want one log file per month, inside the bat file make use of the %DATE% variable to define the log file.

Alvin SIU